# Social-buttons hover effect changing icon color

Tags: ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap, font-awesome

I am using Social Buttons for Bootstrap (http://lipis.github.io/bootstrap-social/) to add icon links to facebook and twitter, but I'm having trouble getting them to behave like the examples on the above site.

The buttons show up fine, but when you hover over them, the icon changes to a darker color. In the examples, this doesn't happen and the icon stays white.

The code I am using for the button:

```
<a class="btn btn-social-icon btn-twitter">
<i class="fa fa-twitter"></i>
```

I'm assuming it has something to do with the btn class, but I'm not able to find anyone else having this issue. Any guidance would be very much appreciated.

Comment: try <a class="btn btn-block btn-social btn-twitter">
            <i class="fa fa-adn"></i> 
 </a>

Comment: Hi Deema,  Thanks, but that just expanded the width of the button, with the same hover behavior.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the answer I needed. Had to modify the button-social-icon:hover color CSS with .btn-social-icon:hover{color:#FFF}

Answer (score 0):

Just add this to the end of your css:

```
.fa:hover{color:#FFF !important;}
```

Comment: Thanks Andrew. That sort of fixed it, but there is a spot where you can hover over the button, and not the icon, which would still show black. So when you move your mouse the the button, you get a sort of flicker. 

I guess it's something that needs to be changed in the btn class, but I'm not sure where.